# zend framework compatible xmpp facebook chat library or sdk

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework, xmpp, facebook-chat

I want to integrate facebook chat to my php zend framework 1.11 project.

Is there any facebook chat xmpp library compatible with zend framework?

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same question for days. Finally I am doing it with [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.0/files/strophe-js.html). Its a great library. You can check [Converse.js](https://conversejs.org/) also.